# I'm filtering few conditions in the excel via Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm FILTERING three conditions in excel column `Task_Name`

- `IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION (PROVIDE)`
- `IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION (CHANGE)`
- `IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION`

and one condition in other column `TAC_NL_Member == True`

I've written code

```
df1=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Admin/desktop/Python/FY19-20 Classic Stats.xlsx', sheet_name="20-Feb",dtype={ 'TAC NL Member': str})

In_Service_Notification=df1.groupby([(df1['Task_Name'] =='IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION ') & (df1['TAC_NL_Member'] == 'True')]).count()
```

Is there any way to filter all the three condition in one go?

I mean all the three condition have this `IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION` in common.

Please suggest if I can filter out this in one go instead using an `or` statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid multiple **or** statements, you can try following solution:

```
filtered_df = df1[(df1['Task_Name'].str.contains('IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION')) & (df1['TAC_NL_Member'] == 'True')]

grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby(filtered_df['Task_Name']).count()
```

@Anand Mishra edit:
I'm getting following out put .

Task_Name   Product_Name    Order_Type  Customer_ID Customer_Name   Distributor_Name    Distributor_Country Installation_Country    Installation_Region Order_Received_Date Order_Due_Date  SALES_ORDER_ID  SubCase_ID  Initial_Queue   Last_Queue  Task_Actual_Start_Date  Task_Actual_End_Date    Task_Estimated_Duration_(in_days)   On-Time_Delivery    Task_Owner_Login    Task_Owner_E-mail   TAC_GESP_Member TAC_NL_Member   TAC_TPEN_Member Closed_by_TAC   Lead_Time_Business_Days SLA_Outcome CLOSED_in_TAC_QUEUE Failure_Reason  Mitigated   Follow-up_Action    Escalation_To
IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION 6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   0   0   0   0
IN SERVICE NOTIFICATION (CHANGE)    3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   1   1   0   0

Is there any way to get only 6 and 3 once 
As there are total 9 instants in the excel file fulling the filtered condition.
Actually I want all the numbers so that I can represent them in excel of power point.

Comment: I'm getting following out put

Comment: @AnandMishra do you want only 6 and 3s (according to your output) or all numbers? Please clarify it

Comment: There are total 9 instance who are fulfilling filter criteria. I want only number in the output . Like total 9 instance match the filter criteria.

Comment: @AnandMishra, if you want only number which represents total 9 instances, then you can try to use "sum" method instead of "count" and limit the number of columns in data frame